# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Embedded Library Include

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Within a Jenkins declarative pipeline, one or more global libraries can be referenced through the Library annotation. ie.

```
@Library(['myLib1', 'myLib2', 'myLib3']) _
```

If `myLib1` is refactored into 2 libraries, all pipelines that reference `myLib1` need to be changed to reference both libraries.

```
@Library(['myLib1.a', 'myLib1.b', 'myLib2', 'myLib3']) _
```

Is there a way to load a dependent library inside a global library? Or some other mechanism that could aggregate including both the libraries in such a way that all the pipelines referencing `myLib1` do not need to be modified to `myLib1.a, myLib1.b`?